# How to send json formatted messages to Slack through Cloud functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send a json formatted message to Slack through a Cloud function using slack_sdk, if I send it like this (not formatted) it works.

```
client = WebClient(token='xoxb-25.......')
    try:
        response = client.chat_postMessage(channel='#random', text=DICTIONARY)
```

I found the documentation on Slack that chat_postMessage supports sending json formats by setting the HTTP headers:

```
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xoxb-25xxxxxxx-xxxx
```

How would that work applied in my code above? I want to send a big python dictionary and would like to receive it formatted in the Slack channel. I tried adding it in multiple ways and deployment fails.
This is the documentation: https://api.slack.com/web

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but I hope this can help others who stumble upon this issue in the future.

I think that you've misunderstood the documentation. The JSON support allows for accepting POST message bodies in JSON format, as only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format was supported earlier. Read more [here](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-10-keeping-up-with-the-jsons#our_friend_json).

To answer your question, you can try to send the dictionary by formatting it or in a code block as Slack API supports markdown.

Reference- [Slack Text Formatting](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting).

Sample Code-

````
from slack_sdk import WebClient
import json
client = WebClient(token="xoxb........-")

json_message = {
    "title": "Tom Sawyer",
    "author": "Twain, Mark",
    "year_written": 1862,
    "edition": "Random House",
    "price": 7.75
}

# format and send as a text block
formatted_text = f"```{json.dumps(json_message, indent = 2)}```"
client.chat_postMessage(channel = "#general", text = formatted_text)

# format and send as a code block
formatted_code_block = json.dumps(json_message, indent = 2)
client.chat_postMessage(channel = "#general", text = formatted_code_block)
````

Output-
[image]